# <command> is a function. How to find where it is defined?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

In Linux Terminal I have a command that I will call pippo

```
#> pippo parameters
...command executed
```

If I call

```
#> which pippo
```

Nothing is shown. If I try `type pippo`, instead, I get:

```
#> type pippo
pippo is a function
pippo ()
{
  ...some code...
}
```

What does it mean "is a function" ?

How to find where it is defined?

And my real problem is why I can't call this function with os.system in python ?

```
#> python executePippo.py
...some unrelated logs...
pippo: not found
```

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is probably load with your environnement profile (for instance in ~/.bashrc).
Here is an example of a function

```
usr@cptr:~$ abc
-bash: abc: command not found
usr@cptr:~$ source test.sh
usr@cptr:~$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
abc(){
    echo hello
}
usr@cptr:~$ rm -f test.sh
usr@cptr:~$ abc
hello
usr@cptr:~$ type abc
abc is a function
abc ()
{
    echo hello
}
usr@cptr:~$ which abc
usr@cptr:~$
```

Comment: it was sourced in a script inside ~/.bashrc